# How make Self-Signed certificate trusted from remote connection

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, remote-access, remote-server, lets-encrypt

I created a self-signed certificate using these commands

```
sudo keytool -genkeypair -alias <MyAlias> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore <MyCert>.p12 -validity 3650

sudo keytool -genkeypair -alias <MyAlias> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore <MyCert>.jks -validity 3650

sudo keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <MyCert>.jks -destkeystore <MyCert>.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12
```

which created a P12 file and a jks file.
If I log in to my server **remotely**, the connection is blocked and an error is shown that indicates your connection is not private, because the certificate is not trusted.

How can I fix this issue?
Maybe I should chain the certificate to another certificate? (example: using Let's Encrypt)?

Answer (score 0):

## Create a Certificate Authority

You can create a Certificate Authority certificate and then sign a certificate with your own CA and then add your CA to the system keychain.

More on that at https://gist.github.com/Soarez/9688998

## Use a Let's Encrypt client

... however, it's probably much easier to use a Let's Encrypt client.

I'm the author so you can take my opinion for a grain of salt, but Greenlock is about the easiest suite of Let's Encrypt / ACME tools available.

### Browser-based client

- https://greenlock.domains

If you use the DNS challenge you can easily get certs for private domains with internal IP addresses as well.

### CLI Clients

If you want it automatic you could use something like [Greenlock CLI](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/greenlock-cli.js) or [Greenlock Express (for node.js)](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/greenlock-express.js)

There's also certbot, but it can be more difficult to install due to it's size, various dependencies, and RAM usage. Greenlock is only about 100kb and has no external dependencies, so it works fine on home servers and memory constrained IoT devices (which is exactly the problem I had when I first wrote it).